# Valve cover breather blowby

Tags: oil

Need HELP!

A built 4cyl engine from a reputable shop with 3000 miles on it!

I have 2 catch cans, one for the PCV and one for the CCV. I get almost nothing in the PCV catch can but i get about 3 ouces in the CCV can if i do 3 full throttle 3rd gear runs.

The PCV valve is new and the can has a 100 psi check valve too.

I get NO leak or blowby out the oil dipstickm just the valve cover breather hose. I know the cover has a baffle on the underside.

If i run the car, in the city etc under 20 psi (only tested to about 20) I get almost nothing the can. If i do wot runs, = blowby.

1. I see it can be piston rings but should i not also get oil from dipstick if it was
   rings being that bad?? Engine builder says i can't have blow-by at high boost and nothing at lower boost if it was rings.
2. I did a leak down test and on on one cylinder i lost about 45% and the coolant external tank level rose. So I see I have that issue and need to change the gasket but i do not see how that can affect the blowby.
3. I notice idle vaccuum acting wierd. Not dropping as low as before. Maybe due to head gasket issue?

No smoke in idel
No smoke reving engine
Oil color ok.
I am able to hit boost
Coolant has dropped slightly lately.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you did the leak down, did you listen to see if you could hear where the loss in the one cylinder was coming from? Also, you never mention the year/make/model of the car or engine ... could you provide that please?

Comment: If you're hearing leak past the rings at 3k miles, either you didn't seat the rings correctly, or the job was botched (I'm thinking the second). If there's an issue with the engine from a "reputable" shop, take it back there. They'll cover their work. There's a problem, let them fix it.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?